# how to delete element created with jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have write this block of code in jquery to create three element after some events

```
$('body').append(
tmp= $('<div id="tmp"></div>')
);

$('<div id="close" />').appendTo("#tmp");   
$('<div id="box-results" />').appendTo('#tmp');
```

this three elements are created normally and added to my DOM but i want to remove them with some function like this :

```
$("#close").click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();
$("#tmp").remove(); 
//$("#overlay").remove(); 
});
```

and after i click close div noting happen ! what's wrong with my code ?

here is online example : [mymagazine.ir/index.php/main/detail/36](http://mymagazine.ir/index.php/main/detail/36) - please find " here is jquery issue" sentence in site because site language is Persian

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to add the click handler on #close *after* you insert the element into the document.

edit providing the requested demo; tested in ff36:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>whatever</title>
 <style type="text/css">
   div {
     border: 1px solid black;
     padding: 0.3em;
   }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function ()
  {
    $('body').append($('<div id="tmp"/>'));
    $('<div id="close">click me</div>').appendTo("#tmp");   
    $('<div id="box-results">contents</div>').appendTo('#tmp');
    $('#close').bind('click', function ()
    {
      $('#tmp').remove();
      return false;
    });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**edit**

change your plugin's code from

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function ()
    {
        $('<div id="close"/>').appendTo($('#tmp'));
    }
});
$('#close').click(function (e) ...);
```

to

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function ()
    {
        $('<div id="close"/>')
            .click(function (e) ...)
            .appendTo($('#tmp'))
        ;
    }
});
```

Comment: could you please show me some code ? you mean like $("#close").live('click', function(){});  if you mean that it's not working either .

Comment: it's not working . this you test that ? is it working for you ?!

Comment: but it's not working for me here is mine http://www.mymagazine.ir/index.php/main/detail/36 - please find " here is jquery issue" sentence in site because site language is Persian

Comment: well, I can see `google.load("jquery", "1.2.6");` in that page.  it's possible it didn't work in that version.  anyway, does the snippet i posted work for you as is?  if yes, try it again with 1.2.6.  does it break then?  it's a simple matter of basic possible cause elimination.

Comment: i use that click handler in plug-in maybe that's my problem ?! and if i use click handler outside my plug-in that way using plug-in is useless

Comment: you can have it inside the plugin, but need to create the element before you attach any event handlers to it (sounds logical, doesn't it? ;)  i've checked your box plugin, and the error was obvious.  see the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Because the elements with ids `#tmp` and `#close` are created dynamically, you can't use the `click` on them directly, you need the **[`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** method instead:

```
$("#close").live('click', function(e){    
  $("#tmp").remove(); 
  return false;
});
```

**`Live()` Description:**

> Attach a handler to the event for all
>   elements which match the current
>   selector, now or in the future.

As can be seen your element is created dynamically (future) not when page was loaded.

**[More Info Here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**

Answer (score 2):

You should use the live method instead of click. It will allow you to add/remove elements without changing their behaviour

```
$("element").live("click", function() { /*do things*/ });
```