# Create and remove HTML-Element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I create a HTML-Element dynamically, do something with it and then it should be removed.
But it is important that it will be really deleted.
Here is my approach:

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.setAttribute('id','MyDiv');
$('#MyDiv').css({'width':'100px','height':'100px'});
$('#MyDiv').html('This is a test');

$('#MyDiv').remove(); // It should be work ?

// Is it possible to delete it as follows?
newdiv.remove();
```

As I mentioned, it is important to really delete the element, since the Function "createElement()" can often get invoked.

How can I test whether the new created HTML-Element is really removed?

I test as follows, whether the element is still existed, but I get always true!

```
alert(  $('#MyDiv').length == 1);
```

Below are a two links, but they were not enough for, in order to solve my problem.

[setting the id attribute of an input element dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851699/setting-the-id-attribute-of-an-input-element-dynamically-in-ie-alternative-for)

[createElement and delete DOMElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022876/how-to-delete-element-created-with-jquery)

Thanks.

Comment: why you need to create a div, edit it and then remove it without even appending it to the dom?

Comment: Your mix of jQuery with plain Javascript hurts a little. Try `newdiv.parentNode.removeChild(newdiv)`.

Comment: you didn't inject newdiv into the DOM, therefore you can't remove it from the DOM. Furthermore the ID of newdiv will be `#MyDiv`, but `$('#MyDiv')` gets the element with the ID `MyDiv`

Comment: As an example I used DIV, it can be any one element. If the item is no longer needed, it must be deleted (due to memory).

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369129/add-remove-dynamically-html-element-with-jquery

Comment: You can't delete it, you'll have to trust the browsers garbage-collection.

Comment: @Ismael:it does not work

Comment: As soon as you do `document.appendChild(newdiv);` it will work fine

Comment: @Dr.Molle: I have already corrected the id. Ok, As you mentioned, the element is not in the DOM, but  how can I delete it anyway?

Comment: That is because `.remove()` is a jQuery method, but you are passing a non-jQuery object to it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one maybe is what you want:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     var div =  document.createElement("div");
     $(function(){
        $("body").append( div);
        $(div).css({'width':'100px','height':'100px','border':'solid 1px black'}).html('This is a test');
        //$(div).remove();
     });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

dont forget to uncoment the //$(div).remove();

Comment: Yes, exactly! That's what I was looking for. It works very well, and the created object can be deleted. :). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I see, you have an error in your code in this line:

```
newdiv.setAttribute('id','#MyDiv')
```

value of id attribute must not have '#' (the hash sign) - with your code element newdiv will have id like "#MyDiv" but this is not valid ID for jQuery, due to jQuery use this template for ID Selector (“#idName”)

You can dynamically delete the element with your way, but I guess previously you should to append it to another element on page using jQuery.append(you element/selector) method

Comment: Ok, it means, if I don't open the element in DOM, then I can not delete it?

Comment: Actually, where the element is generated when not in DOM? I thought that all elements are produced in DOM. Ok, I will investigate better about it :).

Comment: >>then I can not delete it
Nope, you can delete it. The created element placed in memory. You can work with it (newdiv) as you wish. But if you are using jquery and trying to find element by selector it supposes that elements is in DOM, in other case you can't found element.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery you can try with the following:

```
$( "body" ).append( "<div id="MyDiv">This is a test</div>" ); // Create MyDiv div before </body> tag (you can use .prepend( ... ) to create it after <body>)

$("#MyDiv").css({'width':'100px','height':'100px'}); // Give some style to MyDiv

$("#MyDiv").remove(); // Delete MyDiv
```

Comment: Ok, but I want use the function createElement(). It is important for me to delete the created element.

Comment: Check this:
`g=document.createElement('div');
g.setAttribute("id", "MyDiv");
g.innerHTML = "This is a test"`

Comment: `"<div id="MyDiv">This is a test</div>"` produces a syntax error. Use `'<div id="MyDiv">This is a test</div>'` instead.